Ubuntu Desktop 24.04 LTS RDP - Built in Gnome-Remote-Desktop feature - "Encryption Error"
sorry, im far off beeing a linux expert, i know nano, i know vim, i done this and that, things work for years if one get them to work at all, so at the end of the day i got no clue, just to point that out. doing my best i hope, learning.
i want to use linux more for desktop-purposes, but not on/as my main machine, so i set a virtual one up in my proxmox environment, plan was to connect via RDP from windows, and i want to use the built in feature for it, which works up to a point. after a short period, sometimes not even 1 min, sometimes 1 min 30 sec, but never much more than this, the windows rdp client reports an "encryption" error.
to make a long story short, anyone can give me a little "roadmap" how to debug this? thanks for every hint, but i didnt find much on it, or didnt know what to look for.
best regards!

To be clear the error is being given on the Windows machine?

yes, further debugging brought me to the conclusion that it has nothin to do with ubuntu "per se" i guess... i think its proxmox, maybe the network config, cant look further into this tonight, maybe weekend. a second VM on same proxmox node, running ubuntu server with AMP, disconnects all players exactly when i get my rdp error message on my windows rdp client.

to give it a try i set up a windows 10 vm... rdp to this vm works without any problem, but still reproducable rdp connection from my physical pc with windows 11 to ubuntu gnome-remote-desktop, "crashes" the bridge on proxmox causees all running vms loose their connections at the moment the rdp-error occurs, and now things get even more strange, connecting form a win10 vm to ubuntu desktop vm, on same proxmox node, works. no errors... so win11(physical)->rdp->win10vm->rdp->ubuntuvm works... as i mentioned, im not that experienced, dont even know where to start, debuging this
